# MKV files won't play, or plays muted

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, mkv

I have an MKV file here that will play in the default Videos app but muted, and won't play at all in VLC (no error message, but a black screen and no sound). I already installed the recommended codecs for VLC, i.e. I ran the command `sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265`.

When I open the file in Videos it says it can't find the plugin for "media files of the following type: audio/x-unknown decoder", then plays the muted video. Checking the file's properties does indeed show the audio codec as "unknown". I opened it in MediaInfo and it says:

> English, 48.0 KHZ, 32 bits, 2 channels, Opus

So I tried to download the [Opus](http://opus-codec.org/) codec, and Ubuntu told me it was already installed.

Comment: Can you post the full output from mediainfo in your question? If possible it would be great if you could put the file itself online somewhere too...